# How do I add a form in rails that creates 2 models which have a 1-to-many dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models with a 1-to-many association, `Account` which has multiple `User`.

I'd like to have a signup form for accounts that also creates the first user for that account.

My `Account` model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
   validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
end
```

My `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account
   validates :account_id, presence: true
```

How do I create a form that creates an account and a user at the same time, and what needs to go in my `accounts_controller` and my `users_controller`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Nested Forms, like this.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
   validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
end
```

In your form for account use the "fields_for" Helper to add fields for the users of that account.

```
     <div class="field">
2      <%= f.label :account_field1%><br>
3      <%= f.text_field :account_field1%>
4    </div>
5 
6    <h2>Users</h2>
7       <%= f.fields_for :users do |user| %>
8         <div class="user_fields">
9           <div class="field">
10            <%= user.label :name %><br>
11            <%= user.text_field :name %>
12          </div>
13        </div>
14     <% end %>
```

And in your accounts_controller add the users_attributes in the controller strong parameters white list.

```
private
def account_params
  params.require(:account).permit(:account_field1, users_attributes: [ :id, :name ])
end
```